# Is there a way to use Linux on Windows while utilizing nvidia CUDA?

Tags: linux, windows, cuda

VirtualBox cannot use CUDA.

Is there a way around without using dual-boot?

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried WSL? WSL lets you run any Linux distribution on Windows.

There is a WSL-specific guide for CUDA, so it seems supported.

https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/wsl-user-guide/index.html

Comment: Thanks for the possible solution, looking at it right now. If it works this is a life-saver!

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference. You can include the relevant information by [edit]ing your answer here.